# Strange overloading rules in C++

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, g++, overloading

I'm trying to compile this code with GCC 4.5.0:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> void sort(T, T) {}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ g++ -c nm.cpp
nm.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
nm.cpp:9:28: error: call of overloaded ‘sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’ is ambiguous
nm.cpp:4:28: note: candidates are: void sort(T, T) [with T = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.0/../../../../include/c++/4.5.0/bits/stl_algo.h:5199:69: note:                 void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]
```

Comeau compiles this code without errors.
(4.3.10.1 Beta2, strict C++03, no C++0x)

**Is this valid C++?**

**Why is GCC even considering `std::sort` as a valid overload?**

---

I did some experiments, and I think I know why Comeau *might* compile this (but I don't know this for a fact):

```
namespace foo {
typedef int* iterator_a;
class        iterator_b {};
template <typename T> void bar(T) {}
}

template <typename T> void bar(T) {}

int main()
{
    bar(foo::iterator_a()); // this compiles
    bar(foo::iterator_b()); // this doesn't
}
```

My guess is that the first call resolves to `bar(int*)` so there's no ADL and no ambiguity, while the second call resolves to `bar(foo::iterator_b)` and pulls in `foo::bar` (but I'm not really sure).

So GCC probably uses something like `iterator_b` while Comeau uses `iterator_a`.

Comment: I find Comeau behavior strange, this means that their `iterator` don't live in the `std` namespace or am I missing something ?

Comment: I updated the answer with some code that you can play around with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicitly specify your `sort` function by fully qualifying the name as `::sort`.

The ambiguous overload is due to [argument dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup). The C++ standard doesn't specify how `std::vector<*>::iterator` should be implemented. The gcc library writers have chosen to use a template (`__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator`) with a template type argument of `std::vector`, which brings namespace `std` into the list of associated namespaces.

---

*Is this valid C++?*

Yes, but the behaviour of both compilers is also compliant with the C++ standard. ADL presents a huge headache from this perspective and the full consequences weren't understood until after standardization.